# Changing the function of right mouse click in photoshop cs6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6

I want to change Photoshop Right Click panel. i never use Layer list so please tell me if any way to change it....

Thanks in advance

Comment: flagging this as offtopic, this question is not about design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this as the os level, not att the app level, so the answer will depend on your OS. But basically, look for an app such as [Steer Mouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) that will let you customize your mouse functions per app.